# Windows 7 Display Color Calibration tool does not properly set colour settings

Tags: windows-7, display, display-settings, color-profiles, calibration

I just bought a new monitor (LG E2351VR) and was trying to calibrate it with the Windows 7 Display Color Calibration tool. When I attempt to set the display gamma via the software slider, it temporarily changes the gamma but the changes are immediately reverted after a fraction of a second.

I installed the display driver but it was just an ICM file and it didn't change anything. How can I allow the calibration software to properly set display options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by having [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) running. Exit f.lux and the color calibration should work properly.

Comment: I can't be certain that it's the reason but I strongly suspect it to be the case. I clean installed a new copy of Windows and the problem didn't come back. One key difference: this time, no f.lux. Thanks for the answer, even if a bit late!

Comment: thanks, i used f.lux's "disable for an hour" and it didn't work, exiting entirely did work

Answer (score 0):

You could try your Graphics card vendor's calibration tool (ATI or NVIDIA display settings) if your monitor is plugged into one of your graphics cards. They are more trustworthy than Windows calibration tool and have more advanced features + support for a wide range of displays/display configurations.

Comment: Even the ATI Catalyst Software cannot properly set colour. When I go to the Display Settings options, the sliders are constantly being disabled/enabled every second or so; it's as if the software is attempting to gain control of the display but the monitor reneges control immediately.

Comment: hmm.... That's weird. Could it be that you are running at a non-stock high resolution / refresh rate? I don't believe these have anything to do with gamma though.

You could also try to factory-reset your LG monitor's settings manually and see if that works.